# Toggle menu not working for hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, java, css, function, menu

The toggle function for the menu on mobile browsers applies the css but doesn't respond to javascript code. When you click on the menu it should turn the center line invisible but instead it only responds to the css and stays invisible.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

```js
$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  border: 6px solid #061838;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger .line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  background: #061838;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-active .line:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/mtg-logo.png"></a>
  <nav>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="episodes.html">EPISODES</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.patreon.com/podmtg" target="_blank">PATREON</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/podmtg" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons-facebook.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/podmtg" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons-twitter.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/podmtg/" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons-instagram.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="hamburger is-active">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>


  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, the is-active class is toggling, so the javascript is working fine.  Thats all it is supposed to do.  What is your expectation?

Comment: Well I want the three lines to be visible and the middle line turn invisible once its clicked. For some reason when I view it in a browser the toggle doesn't work. It just shows up already invisible and nothing happens when its clicked. @sn3ll

Comment: It works fine in the code snippet above.  I mean, the line starts out invisible, but thats because you have the is-active in your html to start with.  Just remove it from the html.  But the clicking works fine above

Comment: I removed it but its not toggling on the actual website. It doesn't work outside of this thread. Here is the site [podmtg.com](http://podmtg.com)

Comment: Darrius - check your console. It's not working on the website because the javascript code is giving you an error. You have forgotten to import jquery on your actual site so it isn't recognising the selector $(".hamburger"). Add this to your head on the live site, as you have in your question here: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's working now after I added the jQuery and included the toggle code on the html page instead of loading it externally.